# Azure SQL TempDB Temporary Table owner

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, tempdb

In Azure SQL I can query what temp tables currently exist by using the query -

select * from tempdb.sys.tables;

However, I am not able to find who created these. Surely there must be a simple way to find out who created these temp tables! There are links which suggest things, but all of that works on SQL Server, not Azure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> **Permissions**
>
> Any user can create temporary objects in tempdb. Users can
> access only their own objects, unless they receive additional
> permissions. It's possible to revoke the connect permission to tempdb
> to prevent a user from using tempdb. We don't recommend it because
> some routine operations require the use of tempdb.

The tempdb system database is a global resource that's available to all users connected to the instance of SQL Server or connected to Azure SQL Database.

By default, server admin, database owner or a user with required permission can access the tables of tempdb.

This official article on [tempdb database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15) is related to Azure SQL Database. Please go thorugh for more details and better understanding.

Comment: My question is how can we find who created the local and global temporary tables beginning with # and ## which are visible in the query mentioned above, but the owner column does not exist.

Comment: there is no owner name of tempdb. the tempdb is all about database metadata and has no relation with the owner/user. `tempdb` is re-created every time SQL Server is started so that the system always starts with a clean copy of the database. Temporary tables and stored procedures are dropped automatically on disconnect, and no connections are active when the system is shut down.

Comment: UtkarshPal-MT Thanks. But you haven't read my question properly.